# What does this expression entail?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

After the quake, everyone saw the glimmers of **hope on the horizon.**

Comment: This is a well-known expression. What have you found out?

Comment: The context associated to this sentence is essential; you must add this context.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I wouldn't be asking if I had known.‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: It means there are these glimmers ... of hope ... right above the horizon. Sort of adjacent to it. The horizon, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*On the horizon* is an idiomatic expression meaning "imminent or just becoming apparent".  See the [Lexico](https://lexico.com/definition/on-the-horizon) dictionary.

If there is hope on the horizon, that means that people think things will improve in the near future.